# Copy S3 Objects in the same bucket is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to write a Lambda Function which reads an Excel file, converts it to CSV and then puts the source Excel file (.xlsx) in a Folder/Key called `ARCHIVE`

I am using `Boto3` in my Lambda Function for the same.

My code is:

```
       try:
            print("Bucket: ", s3bucket)
            print("Key: ", s3Key)
            copy_source = {
                  'Bucket': s3bucket,
                  'Key': s3Key
                }
            bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(s3bucket)
            bucket.copy(copy_source, destination_s3_loc)
            print("ARCHIVE copy done")
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Error Copying to ARCHIVE: {0}".format(ex))
```

The above code prints the following:

```
Bucket:  adl-dl-data-raw-ue1-dev
Key:  SUPPLY_CHAIN/SOURCE/TXT_3PL - Jan 28.xlsx
ARCHIVE copy done
```

The target path looks like this:

```
destination_s3_loc = "s3://adl-dl-data-raw-ue1-dev/SUPPLY_CHAIN/SOURCE/ARCHIVE/TXT_3PL - Jan 28.xlsx"
```

The code is NOT throwing any errors or exceptions.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
destination_s3_loc = "s3://adl-dl-data-raw-ue1-dev/SUPPLY_CHAIN/SOURCE/ARCHIVE/TXT_3PL - Jan 28.xlsx"
```

to this:

```
destination_s3_loc = "SUPPLY_CHAIN/SOURCE/ARCHIVE/TXT_3PL - Jan 28.xlsx"
```

The [copy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.copy) method expects the destination to be an S3 object key (within the same bucket), not a fully-qualified S3 object URI.